# Conditions to calculate an integral through a series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, entire-functions, analytic-continuation

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R_+}$ be Lebesgue integrable functions. We can show that if $g$ has compact support and $f$ has a Maclaurin series that converges absolutely in the support of $g$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) g(x) dx &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\mu_k}{k!}f^{(k)}(0),
\end{align*}
where $\mu_k = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^k g(x) dx$ is the $k$th moment of $g$.

I would like to know if it is possible to substitute the compact support hypothesis for a more general one that lets $\mathrm{supp}(g) = \mathbb{R}$ and includes the case $f(x) = g(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

Perhaps, it may help to know that the case $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x) = e^{-|x|}$ does not work.

---

**My attempt:** Since $f$ admits a Taylor expansion around $0$ that converges in $\mathrm{supp}(g)$, then
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) g(x) dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(0) g(x) dx.
\end{align*}
For the compact support case, we have that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x^k g(x)| dx \le M^k \|g\|_1$, for some positive constant $M$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|\frac{x^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(0) g(x)\right| dx \le \|g\|_1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{M^k}{k!}|f^{(k)}(0)| .
\end{align*}
The right-hand side is finite because of the absolutely convergent hypothesis. Then, by [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem), we have that we can interchange the integral with the sum and the result holds.

On the other hand, if $g$ does not have compact support, I'm afraid we must ask that $|\mu_k| \le  \|g\|_1 M^k$ for some positive constant $M$, otherwise there is no guarantee of convergence. The problem with this condition is that it does not even include the example I provided.

Comment: $\int |g(x)|e^{|x|}dx<\infty$ and $(f^{k}(0))$ bounded would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed a sufficient condition. However, I need a weaker condition, because $f^{(k)}(0)$ bounded is not true for the provided example.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake in calculating $f^{k}(0)$ in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, I did not think there would be an answer, because the series of the example is not absolutely convergent (thanks for bringing that up @StevenClark), and most of the results I'm familiar with require absolute convergence in some form.

However, I believe I have found a condition that includes, at least some, of the cases of conditional convergence. The condition that replaces compact support of $g$ is
\begin{align}
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{|\mu_n|}{n!}|f^{(n)}(x)| = 0.
\end{align}

To prove this, we use the [mean-value form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) to show that there exists a function $\xi:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
  \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) g(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \frac{\mu_k}{k!} f^{(k)}(0)
    + \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{n!} x^n g(x) dx.
\end{align*}
But,
\begin{align*}
  \left|\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{n!} x^n g(x) dx \right| \le \frac{\mu_n}{n!} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f^{(n)}(x)|.
\end{align*}
Therefore, if condition (1) holds, then the original identity must hold.

---

**Mild verification:** Let us apply the condition to the provided examples.

1. Let $f(x)=g(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials), we have that condition (1) becomes
   \begin{align*}
     \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{|\mu_n|}{n!}|f^{(n)}(x)|
       \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1+n}{2})}{\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{2})} \to 0.
   \end{align*}
2. For the case $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\mu_n = 2(n!)$ and the series coefficient of $f$ is $1/(n/2)!$ for even $n$. Then, condition (1) does not hold.

Checked!

---

**Additional comment:** Perhaps, there is a way to extend the result by removing the $\sup$ in condition (1), because the power series of $f$ is absolutely convergent and we can extend $f$ analytically to an [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).